# MySQL : weekly and monthly average

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is my **bill** table:

```
shop_id | billing_date | total
------------------------------
ABC     | 2016-03-07   | 100
ABC     | 2016-03-14   | 200
DEF     | 2016-03-07   | 300
DEF     | 2016-03-14   | 100
GHI     | 2016-03-07   | 30
```

I want to get one line per shop, with **average total per week**, the **current month total**, and the **average total per month**. This final data must look like this:

```
shop | weekly avg. | current month total | monthly avg.
-------------------------------------------------------
ABC  | 150         | 300                 | 300
DEF  | 200         | 500                 | 500
GHI  | 30          | 30                  | 30
```

My question is: Is it possible to get this informations directly from an SQL query?

Comment: Yes and what have you tried so far? Please feel free to share with us.

Comment: I have tried grouping by week like this : SELECT shop_id, avg(total) as weekly_avg FROM bill b GROUP BY shop_id, WEEKOFYEAR(billing_date); But I'm far from the solution. I think I have to make Sub-Queries but can't figure out how...

Comment: There is a contradiction between AVG by week and AVG by month to be in one single result row - which week should be there? and why monthly AVG of ABC is 300 - what is the difference between SUM and AVG for this shop?

Comment: @mitkosoft my sample data is probably not revelant because there is only one month here. For each shop, I want to know the average amount sold per week and per month. If a shop made a total of 500$ for january, and 300$ for february, the average by month should be 400. I hope I answered your question, my english is poor...

Comment: AVG by month is clear, AVG by week is the problem - what do you want there as final result?

Comment: The AVG per week will be a revelant information mostly for the current month, because for previous month, It will be something like (AVG by month / 4.2). The application offers the possibility to filter the results with a date_from, date_to, and for small periods, the AVG by week will be revelant. Am I answering your question?

Comment: How do you define 'current month'?

Comment: @DylanSu it's just an "unfinished month". I want statistics about sales : during the current month, I can't compare the sales with previous monthes because it's just a portion of the month. The AVG by week is just a comparison basis for smaller periods than monthes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you can try this way for current year using `WEEK` and `MONTH` of mysql. as per your data entries in table is week wise:

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7cab/6)

```
select shop_id,(sum(total)/(WEEK(MAX(bdate)) - WEEK(MIN(bdate))+1)) as weekly_avg,(sum(total)/(MONTH(MAX(bdate))-MONTH(MIN(bdate))+1)) as mothly_avg, sum( case when MONTH(bdate) = MONTH(NOW()) then total else 0 end) as current_month_total  from bill group by shop_id WHERE YEAR(bdate) = 2016
```

For number of year greater than one

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a5f2/1)

```
select shop_id,
sum(total)/(12 * (YEAR(MAX(bdate)) - YEAR(MIN(bdate))) + (MONTH(MAX(bdate)) - MONTH(MIN(bdate)))+1) as month_avg,
sum(total)/(7 * (YEAR(MAX(bdate)) - YEAR(MIN(bdate))) + (WEEK(MAX(bdate)) - WEEK(MIN(bdate)))+1) as weekly_avg,
sum( case when YEAR(bdate) = YEAR(bdate) and MONTH(bdate) = MONTH(NOW()) then total else 0 end) as current_month_total from bill group by shop_id
```

Comment: Hey, I've just tested it quickly an the results seems good :) I'll will implement this later today and I'll let you know ;) Thank you very much !

Comment: this may have unexpected results when date range extends more than a year

Comment: @LuisSiquot i have already putted filter for year in `where` clause of current year

Comment: This kind of query only works for datas within a year? What if I want the AVG by month based on sales from many years?

Comment: @VishalJAIN Nailed it!! You are awsome ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of thing you are after??:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(bill.shop_id),wk as WeeklyTotal,mt as MonthlyTotal,ma as MonthlyAverage
FROM bill
JOIN (SELECT AVG(total) wk,shop_id
    FROM bill
    WHERE YEAR(billing_date) = 2016 AND MONTH(billing_date) = 1
    GROUP BY shop_id) as weekly ON bill.shop_id = weekly.shop_id
JOIN (SELECT SUM(total) mt,shop_id
    FROM bill
    WHERE YEAR(billing_date) = 2016 AND MONTH(billing_date) = 1
    GROUP BY CONCAT(shop_id,MONTH(billing_date))
    ) month_total ON month_total.shop_id = bill.shop_id
JOIN (SELECT AVG(total) ma,shop_id
    FROM bill
    WHERE YEAR(billing_date) = 2016 AND MONTH(billing_date) = 1
    GROUP BY CONCAT(shop_id,MONTH(billing_date))
) month_avg ON month_avg.shop_id = bill.shop_id
```

Comment: No, this query returs multiple lines per shop ;)

Comment: I get this message : Column 'shop_id' in field list is ambiguous (I use Doctrine 2 raw query)

Comment: I'm sorry but this query still returns multiple lines per shop :(

Comment: I expect it was returning multiple months - try that.

Comment: Ok, the results looks ok but the is a large difference with those from the top rated answer. I will try it on an small amount of data and let you know ;) thank you dude !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using conditional aggregation and conditional logic:

```
select shop_id,
       sum(total) / (7 * datediff(max(billing_date), min(billing_date)) + 1) as avg_weekly,
       sum(case when year(billing_date) = year(now()) and month(billing_date) = month(now()) then total else 0 end) as curr_Month,
       (sum(total) /
        (year(max(billing_date)) * 12 + month(max(billing_date)) - 
         year(min(billing_date)) * 12 + month(min(billing_date))
             ) + 1
        )
       ) as avg_month
total else 0 end) as week_total
from bill
gropu by shop_id;
```

Comment: Something is broken with this query, there is a mess with parenthesis but I can't find where is the problem...